# How to inspect shared buffers in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I found this [shared buffers how to look into](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/shared_buffers-looking-into-the-postgresql-i-o-cache/) usefull link.
My tables

```
 Schema |           Name            |   Type   |  Owner   |    Size    | Description 
--------+---------------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------
 public | course                    | table    | postgres | 16 kB      | 
 public | documents                 | table    | postgres | 8192 bytes | 
 public | documents_document_id_seq | sequence | postgres | 8192 bytes | 
 public | enrolled                  | table    | postgres | 16 kB      | 
 public | pg_buffercache            | view     | postgres | 0 bytes    | 
 public | student                   | table    | postgres | 8192 bytes | 
 public | student_sid_seq           | sequence | postgres | 8192 bytes | 
 public | testdecimals              | table    | postgres | 496 MB     | 
 public | testreals                 | table    | postgres | 346 MB     |
```

I try to run this file for testreals

```
SELECT c.relname, c.relkind, count(*)
FROM pg_database AS a, pg_buffercache AS b, pg_class AS c
WHERE c.relfilenode = b.relfilenode
AND b.reldatabase = a.oid
AND c.oid >= 16384
AND a.datname = 'testreals'
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 3 DESC, 1;
```

It does not work.I am newbie to PostgreSQL.

```
 relname | relkind | count 
---------+---------+-------
(0 rows)
```

What do `.oid` and `.relfilenode` stand for?
How to edit the code, to inspect shared buffers for this table?

I tried what Laurentz suggested

```
select * from testdecimals limit 10;
select * from testreals limit 10;
```

Now I have output

```
   relname    | relkind | count 
--------------+---------+-------
 testreals    | r       |    33
 testdecimals | r       |     1
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two explanations for what you observe:

- There is no database `testreals`.
- No table, index, sequence or materialized view in the database `testreals` has been touched since the database server was started, so nothing is cached.

Try and `SELECT` from a table in that database, then try the query again.

`oid` is the object ID, which for metadata tables like the ones in your query identifies the object (the database in the case of `pg_database` and the table or index or sequence or materialized view in the case of `pg_class`).

`relfilenode` is the name of the file storing the data in a table or index or sequence or materialized view.

See [the documentation for the system catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html) for details.